# The action you have requested is invalid

Tags: ee2, members, error, forms

I am using EE 2.4

Dummy signup: http://tensports.zeecdn.com/test-login-native.php

When I click on register it gives me an error **The action you have requested is invalid.**

I am submitting a form with *action ="http://tensports.zeecdn.com/ee/index.php/register/login-signup"*

Can I get some guidance on this?

In case if you want to refer the code :

```
<form id="signupForm" action="<?php echo $STATIC_URL;?>ee/index.php/register/login-signup" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="form_status" name="form_status" value="signup">
    <li class="emId remReg"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:validate_signup();"
        class="acLogin">Register</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

my template:

http://codepad.org/eaKqsvTJ

Comment: Please share the code you are using. Narrow it down to a specific snippet of code which can recreate the issue. It would also help to explain why you linked to a raw PHP file - is that part of ExpressionEngine?

Comment: @AdrianMacneil:the problem is it just does not go in to template that I created in register group...I could give you the code...narrow it down too...but my area of concern is the data just does not go to this template..wait i will share the code

Comment: Try adding a secure forms hash to your form: `<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}" />`.

Comment: @DerekHogue: can i get a link or something to know about secure forms..Have u faced this problem before?

Comment: Yes, I have -- though not until 2.7, when they tightened-up secure forms further. [Bjørn's answer is on the money.](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/17254/55)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get that error if you have secure forms enabled, and you submit a form without including a valid XID in the post.

More here:
http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/putting-the-secure-in-secure-mode-forms

Add this to your form:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}">
```

You can disable secure forms in your config, although this is not recommended:

```
$config['secure_forms'] = "n";
```

Comment: I have used your solution to fix my forms and they're working, however I have a few text fields in them that use ajax to autocomplete and they are giving me this error too, I don't know how to fix that. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer to my problem was here: [link](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/guidelines/security.html#ajax)